# Predicting dissociation energy of diatomic iodine computationally

Tags: bond, computational-chemistry, spectroscopy

In one of my classes we used ORCA with three different functionals: BP86, B3LYP, and M06-L, all with the basis set def2-SVP. In addition to calculations we did it experimentally by a Deslandres table and a Birge-Sponer plot. The experimental values for the most part match the values given in NIST, however for the three functionals my $D_{0}^{"}$ value is twice as big as the value given in NIST, and I don't know why. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! Feel free to take the [tour] to learn more about this site. In order to be actually able to help you, it would be good to if you could [edit] the values you have obtained/ researched into the question. Please also share what your thoughts are on the matter.

Comment: Are you making a distinction between $D_{0}$ and $D_{0}^{"}$?